# In Java what's the best way to get the last 250 characters of a string?

Tags: java, string

In Java what's the best way to get the last 250 characters of a string?

The string maybe empty, less than and greater than 250 chars.

Thanks

Comment: What have you already tried? Hint: it's likely to use `substring`, but you need to work out where to take the substring from...

Comment: I'm thinking, [`String#isEmpty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29), [`String#length`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) and [`Math.min`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28int,%20int%29) are what you need to read up on

Comment: 'Best' by which criteria? Or do you mean "How to get the last 205 characters of a String?"

Comment: If the string can be less that 250 characters your question is meaningless as stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what you what, but this can do it:

```
if(string.length() > 250) {
     char[] lastCharacters = (string.subString(string.length-250)).toCharArray;
}
```

Comment: I was downvoted when I answered the same way, but timmeke gets an upvote?

Answer (score 4):

I would use [StringUtils.right](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#right%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) from Commons Lang, examples:

```
StringUtils.right("abc", 0)   = ""
StringUtils.right("abc", 2)   = "bc"
StringUtils.right("abc", 4)   = "abc"
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest would be like this :-

```
public class check2 {
    public static void main(String main[])
    {
        String temp = "Your String Of Some Size";
        if(temp.length()>=250)
        {
            System.out.println(temp.substring(temp.length()-250));

        }
        else
        {
            //Since Size is less than 250 ,i display the same string
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a more compact way to do it:

```
public String getLast250Char(String input) {
        return (input != null && input.length() > 250) ? input.substring(-250) : input;
}
```

Doing like this, you'll get a `null` return value once your `input` string is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class twofiftystring{
    public static void main(String main[])
    {
        String somestring = "String of arbitrary size";
        String res = temp.length()>=250 ? somestring.substring(temp.length()-250 : somestring;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
string.substring(Math.max(0, string.length() - 250));
```

The [`Math.max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max%28int,%20int%29) should work by selecting the highest positive value between 2 numbers provided.

Comment: This will fail if the length is less than 250, which is a case explicitly called out in the question.

Comment: So you've now answered the easiest case. I don't think that's particularly helpful.

Comment: Ok, updated the post. This should help.

Answer (score 0):

This method will return the last 250 characters in the string, and else just return the string.
You can modify it to return an exception if the string has to be 250 characters or longer.

```
public String getLast250Characters(String text)
{
    return (text.length() <= 250) ? text : text.substring((text.length() - 250));
}
```